# how display ArrayCollection in group with ITEMRENDER | ACTIONSCRIPT

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, arraycollection

i got an Arraycollection which holds other arrays in it. 
i want to display the data inside with an item render but cant manage to do this
here is example code to explain my question

```
<s:DataGroup dataProvider="{news}"
                 itemRenderer="components.displaynews">
```

and this is the item render

```
 <s:Label text="{data.??/}"/>
```

now what i dont understand is what comes after data? in the array collection the data goes like this :   myArrayCollection->[0]->firstname

so when im binding data to item render,how do i represent the [x] to get to the specific name that i want? this obviusly wont work

```
<s:Label text="{data.[0].name/}"/>
```

and one more thing is what is the lightest way to display data in a list\group with simple item render (image and text)

thanks ahead
10x for your help!

```
            private function convertFBEventData2TreeData(eventData:Object):Object
        {
            var children:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            var numAttrs:Number = 0;
            for (var attrName:String in eventData)
            {
                var val:Object = eventData[attrName];   
                if (val != null)
                    children.addItem({label:attrName, children:convertFBEventData2TreeData(val)});
                numAttrs++;
            }
            if (numAttrs == 0 && eventData != null)
            {
                children.addItem({label:eventData});
            }
            return children;
        }
```

this is my data

```
eventData   [] (@cb73bc9)   
[0] Object (@a3f9461)   
    actions [] (@cb736f1)   
    application null    
    created_time    "2011-07-29T11:46:31+0000"  
    from    Object (@a49c179)   
    id  "100002237793631_139378476146745"   
    message "2 And a half days on a 546 mile load just to find out they wont except the load,when we should b doin 1000 miles a day,somebody needs to get their shit together"  
    type    "status"    
    updated_time    "2011-07-29T11:46:31+0000"  
[1] Object (@ca53239)   
[2] Object (@d023a49)   
[3] Object (@d029059)   
[4] Object (@cb796e9)   
[5] Object (@d023ce9)   
[6] Object (@cb79809)   
[7] Object (@a49c6e9)   
[8] Object (@d0238c9)   
[9] Object (@d029a19)   
[10]    Object (@ca53509)   
[11]    Object (@d0261a9)   
[12]    Object (@a5b5a91)   
[13]    Object (@cb79a61)   
[14]    Object (@d025761)   
[15]    Object (@d023b09)   
[16]    Object (@a49c521)   
[17]    Object (@d0258e1)   
[18]    Object (@d0232b1)   
[19]    Object (@cb80c11)   
[20]    Object (@cb3e4c1)   
[21]    Object (@a5b25f9)   
[22]    Object (@d074491)   
[23]    Object (@d02f9e9)   
[24]    Object (@d024b81)   
length  25 [0x19]
```

is there a way to display it with item render?? i cant manage to do it

and i converted it to arraycollection with the code above and then the data looked like this:

```
resultsData mx.collections.ArrayCollection (@918cec1)   
[inherited] 
[0] Object (@d023779)   
[1] Object (@d024f29)   
    children    mx.collections.ArrayCollection (@ca1bac1)   
        [inherited] 
        [0] Object (@d0247a9)   
            children    mx.collections.ArrayCollection (@ca1bb01)   
            label   "updated_time"  
        [1] Object (@d0254f1)   
            children    mx.collections.ArrayCollection (@ca1bb41)   
            label   "id"    
        [2] Object (@d026d31)   
            children    mx.collections.ArrayCollection (@ca1bc01)   
            label   "from"  
        [3] Object (@d029461)   
            children    mx.collections.ArrayCollection (@ca1bcc1)   
            label   "link"  
        [4] Object (@d029b81)   
            children    mx.collections.ArrayCollection (@ca1bd01)   
            label   "type"  
        [5] Object (@d029b39)   
        [6] Object (@d02d491)   
        [7] Object (@d076671)   
        [8] Object (@d06f941)   
        [9] Object (@cb3e629)   
        [10]    Object (@d0235e1)   
        [11]    Object (@d0239b9)   
        [12]    Object (@d024ef9)   
        source  [] (@d07e0d9)   
    label   "1" 
[2] Object (@d023269)   
[3] Object (@d02f941)   
[4] Object (@d02d6d1)   
[5] Object (@d023479)   
[6] Object (@d076491)   
[7] Object (@cb3ea19)   
[8] Object (@cf9b4a9)   
[9] Object (@cf992f9)   
[10]    Object (@cfac689)   
[11]    Object (@cfa9d19)   
[12]    Object (@d0797d9)   
[13]    Object (@d02b2b1)   
[14]    Object (@d02ffb9)   
[15]    Object (@d025ca1)   
[16]    Object (@cfa2629)   
[17]    Object (@cfac2c9)   
[18]    Object (@cfb8c71)   
[19]    Object (@cfc4bb1)   
[20]    Object (@cfb8a91)   
[21]    Object (@cf99bb1)   
[22]    Object (@d0ad569)   
[23]    Object (@c9681f1)   
[24]    Object (@d0a7959)   
source  [] (@ca7c061)
```

and i also cant think of a way to make it displayed in an item render!

the item render code is rather simple

```
<label text={data.??">
```

i dont know what to add after data, i tried many things but nothing work \:

Comment: Post a sample of your data and post your current renderer "displaynews" don't be shy with your code we won't laugh

Comment: im adding it in my question and my code is a bit shitty \:

Comment: ok just figured out something! when im writing inside my app <label text={news[0].type} it works.   but when im typing inside the item render <label text={data[0].type}> although im providing in my app DATAPROVIDER={news}  the error is TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@c80cb79 to mx.collections.IList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item render has a function called `set data` which is called automatically behind the scenes (in the parent class). So data, is not an array... its your ROW. So you need to do simply `{data.name}` assuming that an object is in your array collection with the property "name".

If your array collection is simply strings... then you just use `{data}`. If you've got an object with an image location and a name, then simply bind to those properties the same way you did to name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 10x for your answer but i still cant manage to do that. what do i do when i have an arraycollection that contains other objects in it, that contains other objects inside of it? for example  myarray-->male-->over30-->name-->david/ how do i display "david" with the item render? 10x

Comment: Can you show some code? I'm confused of your array/object structure.

Comment: ofcourse. what im doing is acctually reciving "newsfeed" from FACEBOOK im reciving an object im converting it to an array. ADDED THE CODE TO MY QUESTION. after im converting the object from facebook into an arraycollection i want to "print" it, but i need full control over what im printing. in case of "status" do this and in other case do this. but i cant even manage to "print" the objects inside using item render. 10x alot for your help!!!

Comment: I didn't realize this was hierarchical. It's a bit of a loaded response now, basically you need to learn to override the `set data` function. If you trace it in debug mode you'll see that function receives your data object with the label and children properties. Based on that, you set the values in your item renderer. This link has a good explanation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html#WSdfd41de286dc919d-63248ba71211ccd7b7c-7fff

Comment: thanks  alot for your answers and patience [= btw is there an easier way to display the data inside(and with less control) im just looking for to go over the entire data and in case i find "x" print it

Comment: nevermind my friend i read the stuuf in the link you gave and its hlps alot. 10x again [=